# How can I use node npm package "Cryptr" in angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I want to use `cryptr`(node.js package) npm package in angular. I am doing like this:

```
declare var require: any;

const Cryptr = require('cryptr');
const cryptr = new Cryptr('my-phrase');
```

But it throws an error because in node.js there is `require` type implementation. It throws an error like this

> ERROR in ./node_modules/cryptr/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'crypto' in
>   'D:\FreelanceProjects\ReferlingProject(Melvin)\referral-sow\node_modules\cryptr'

How can I use this package in `angular` app that is build for `node.js`?

Comment: Just to be sure, u ran `npm i cryptr` ?

Comment: If you use this library as front end, don't you think that someone can get the secret just in reading the source ? Won't it be more secure if the job is done at backend ?

Comment: @Angular yes i ran this.

Comment: @PimentoWeb can you tell me the solution?

Comment: Create a server function, call it with fetch, and return the result...